# AttributeError: 'TestSuite' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I'm writing Django unit test for Login form. Below is my sample code.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TestSuite(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'password': 'secret'}
        User.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)

    def test_login(self):
        # send login data
        response = self.client.post('/accounts/login', self.credentials, follow=True)
        # should be logged in now
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active)
```

But when I'm executing from my console it's throwing the below error.

**Traceback**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_login (accounts.tests.test_form.TestSuite)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django\webapplication\accounts\tests\test_form.py", line 15, in test_login
    response = self.client.post('/accounts/login', self.credentials, follow=True)
AttributeError: 'TestSuite' object has no attribute 'client'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.502s
```

Comment: As a side note: naming a test case "TestSuite" [can be a bit confusing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite)

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers ok...So I'll rename it to TestForm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **python** `unittest` module has not `client` in it; You should use `django.test`.

Simply change your first line as:

```
from django.test import TestCase
```

Read more about [different test classes available to use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#provided-test-case-classes).

Comment: Thank you its working..but one more question I've..the line self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active) is giving the error like AssertionError: False is not true... when I'm printing print(response.context['user']) its giving AnonymousUser....Can you plz clarify me on this?

Comment: @Amlanjyoti Testing the "login" in this way is a bit strange. I think you're looking for `login` or probably `force_login` method; Check them in the docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need django.test TestCase, instead of unittest's.